# Override vuetify 3 breakpoints globally

Tags: vuejs3, vite, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm currently using vuetify 3 with nuxt 3 and I need to customize the grid-breakpoint globally in scss. I have tried different solutions propose in the documentations and nothing seems to work.
I followed the guide here https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/ and it didn't work

// ./assets/styles/main.scss

```
@forward 'vuetify/settings' with (
$grid-breakpoints: (
  'xs': 0,
  'sm': 390px,
  'md': 768px,
  'lg': 1024px,
  'xl': 1440px,
  'xxl': 1920px,
)
);
```

included it in app.vue

```
<style lang="scss">
@use './assets/styles/main';
</style>
```

my expectation was to have see the view port changes occur at those breakpoints, but the default vuetify breakpoints are still applied.

```
<v-row>
  <v-col
    v-for="(category, index2) in section.categories"
    :key="index2"
    cols="12"
    lg="4"
  >
...
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

I expected to see 3 columns at a view width off `1025px` upward, but this is the case only from  `1280px`

Comment: Did you solved your problem?